# Erro: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit

Tenho uma aplicação `Android`, utilizando a biblioteca `Retrofit` para manipular `requests`, ao tentar fazer qualquer `request` em um `android` 5.0 ou inferior, recebo o seguinte `log`:

> I/call: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Utilizando `android` superior á versão 5.0, consigo fazer as `requests` normalmente. A aplicação está consumindo uma `API` própria, que utiliza `SSL`.

Comment: Vê se essa resposta te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34533863/2570426

Comment: Tem este artigo também que resolveu para outras pessoas: http://steveliles.github.io/android_ssl_certificate_not_trusted.html

Answer (score -3):

O erro `"Trust anchor for certification path not found"` geralmente ocorre quando o sistema Android não consegue verificar a autenticidade do certificado SSL do servidor da API que você está acessando. Isso pode ser causado por vários motivos, mas uma possível causa é que o certificado raiz do servidor não está presente na lista de certificados confiáveis do dispositivo Android. No entanto, é importante considerar outras causas possíveis também.

**Como resolver ?**

`Atualize o dispositivo Android:` Certifique-se de que o dispositivo Android com versão 5.0 ou inferior esteja atualizado com as atualizações mais recentes de segurança. Às vezes, as atualizações de segurança incluem certificados raiz adicionais.

```
Verifique o Certificado do Servidor:
```

Certifique-se de que o certificado SSL do servidor da API esteja configurado corretamente e não tenha expirado.
Certifique-se de que o servidor esteja enviando a cadeia de certificados completa, incluindo o certificado intermediário e o certificado raiz.

`Use um Certificado de Autoridade Certificadora (CA) Comum:` Tente usar um certificado raiz que seja amplamente reconhecido pelos dispositivos Android. Evite usar certificados autoassinados, pois eles podem ser menos confiáveis em dispositivos Android mais antigos.

Adicione o Certificado Manualmente (não recomendado):

Embora não seja a solução ideal, você pode adicionar manualmente o certificado raiz do servidor ao dispositivo Android para contornar o problema. Isso não é recomendado em um ambiente de produção, mas pode ser útil para fins de teste e desenvolvimento.
Para fazer isso, você pode usar o utilitário `"KeyChain"` no Android para instalar o certificado. Lembre-se de remover essa configuração quando for implantar a aplicação em produção.
Verifique as Configurações de Rede: Verifique se não há problemas com as configurações de rede do dispositivo que podem estar interferindo na comunicação com o servidor.

`Verifique as Configurações do Retrofit:` Certifique-se de que as configurações do Retrofit estejam corretas e não estejam ignorando a verificação do certificado SSL. Você pode configurar um OkHttpClient personalizado com um TrustManager personalizado para lidar com certificados personalizados, mas isso requer um conhecimento avançado de segurança SSL.

`Logs Detalhados:` Para obter informações mais detalhadas sobre o erro, você pode ativar os logs do Retrofit para verificar os detalhes do erro SSL. Isso pode ajudar a identificar a causa raiz do problema.

Tenha em mente que a segurança SSL é crítica, e contornar verificações de certificado SSL pode expor seu aplicativo a riscos de segurança. Portanto, é importante garantir que sua configuração SSL seja segura e confiável, e usar certificados confiáveis em ambientes de produção.